# How to delete rows from a pandas dataframe based on certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id       stat_day         x    y
0       2016-03-29        0    3
1       2016-03-29        0    4
2       2016-03-30        0    2
```

How to delete the lines where both `x` and `y` are equal to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'stat_day':['2016-03-29','2016-03-29','2016-03-30'],'x':[0,0,0],'y':[3,4,2]})
df=df.loc[df[['x','y']].values.any(axis=1)]
```

In your example there are no such lines (where both `x` and `y` are 0) so `df` will stay the same, but if you define it so that in the first row both of them are 0, like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'stat_day':['2016-03-29','2016-03-29','2016-03-30'],'x':[0,0,0],'y':[0,4,2]})
df=df.loc[df[['x','y']].values.any(axis=1)]
```

then `df` is

```
    stat_day    x   y
1   2016-03-29  0   4
2   2016-03-30  0   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], (10, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])

   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  0  1
7  1  0
8  1  0
9  0  0
```

***option 1***
`pd.DataFrame.query`

```
df.query('x != 0 or y != 0')

   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  1
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  0  1
7  1  0
8  1  0
```

***option 2***
boolean slicing

```
df[df.x.ne(0) | df.y.ne(0)]

   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  1
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  0  1
7  1  0
8  1  0
```

***option 3***
boolean slicing take 2

```
df[df.astype(bool).any(1)]

   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  1
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  0  1
7  1  0
8  1  0
```

Comment: Last the best. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean series that equals `False` when both x and y are zero and `True` otherwise. This translates into `df.x != 0 | df.y !=0`. Hence something like this might work:

```
df = df[(df.x != 0) | (df.y != 0)]
```

Comment: You should explain your code more so that other people understand your answer better.